# Is this a correct translation for "A new world awaits"

Tags: traducción

This is for an ad I'm making. I translated "A new world awaits" like this:

"Un nuevo mundo le espera"

I think it's correct, but I'm no expert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct and you could leave it like that. That being said I'll add a couple of options so you can choose the one that works best for the way you want your ad to deliver the message.

If you translate this phrase the way you did you are, what it is called, "hablando de usted" it means that you are addressing the person who listens to your message in a respectful way.

If you want to address the person in a friendlier or less formal way you could say:

> Un nuevo mundo te espera.

Or you could very well remove the (if I remember my grammar correctly) pronoun, and just leave it like:

> Un nuevo mundo espera.

That way you are not specifying if you are addressing the person in a respectful or friendly way but, you are also not specifying that the world is waiting for someone or for something or what.

Hope this helps.